# Trim Char fields

Tags: delphi, firebird

We are currently using Delphi with Borland database. We are planning to move from borland to Firebird libraries, (borland lib has mem leaks).

The problem that we are having now is, Firebird library returns a char with trailing spaces, which was somehow handled borland library. We have huge code written without any trimming.

So now if 'abc' is stored in char(10) field, it returns 'abc       '. and our code fails. I was wondering if there is some configuration that I can do on the DB or firebird library to automatically trim char fields.

Comment: Try setting the `TStringField.FixedChar` property to `False`. By default, a `CHAR` field is true, meaning it's a fixed width; I think (but don't have any `CHAR` columns to test against) if it's false it will trim the trailing spaces.

Comment: @Ken - Last time I played with it, [it had no effect](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=65550). But this might have changed...

Comment: @Sertac, thanks. That's why I posted as a comment and not an answer; I wasn't sure. :) An alternate method is to use the field's `OnGetText` event to do the trimming, but that requires changes if you haven't already been using persistent fields.

Comment: Which components are you using? For example FIBPlus has char field trimming as an option property on a dataset.

Comment: Is VarChar(10) syntax allowed in FireBird ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Why don't you just change fields types in a database from CHAR to VARCHAR?
2. You can use TRIM() function in SELECT statement.
3. You can put a couple of changes into IBX source codes in order to right trim CHAR
   strings.

Comment: My manager would not agree with the first two options, as we don't want to spend too much time in this change. What do you mean by 3rd option?

Comment: I'm very tempted to downvote this because of the third bullet. Changing the IBX source because you designed your database is absolutely the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: I think it is a bit tongue in cheek, and it is the only real way if the TS doesn't want to go with the first two options.

Comment: @Ali Why wouldn't your manager agree to the first two options, those are the only sensible solutions to this problem.

Comment: @Mark: It's a bad joke if it's not clear that it is meant to be one, especially when posted to someone who may be a new developer and not know it's a joke. It was posted as if it were a serious third option (which I think it was intended to be, BTW). And modifying source that's part of the VCL is a bad idea; it breaks updates because the files no longer match, and you have to also apply the hack to any new releases of the VCL in the future. Using a proper fix is almost always a better solution.

Answer (score 9):

This is per the requirements laid down in the SQL standards: CHAR fields should be returned padded with spaces to the maximum defined length. If you don't want that behaviour, you need to use VARCHAR instead of CHAR.

Update: Not sure if it is helpful, but according to this [message](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2004/1/34602.html) you could create a workaround if you are using IBX.

Comment: Agreed. But is there a way around for this?

Comment: Your only options are the ones described by Andrei K., or you will need to trim the string yourself in your application.

Comment: @Ali - if you're using a ClientDataSet set 'DisableStringTrim' to false, or have a look at 'Trim Char' parameter if you're using a 'TSQLConnection'. But these will have a global effect.

Comment: How can I automatically change all the char fields to varchar? Some system table change or ..?

Comment: Using [ALTER TABLE](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-table.html#langrefupd25-alter-table). You should never make direct changes to the system tables (unless there is no DDL to perform the change otherwise)